# Replace tag in xaml VS2010 xaml editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf, xaml

Is there a possibility in the xaml editor to replace a particular tag, so that it automatically replaces the corresponding closing tag?

my current workflow:

I'm starting with this xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

then, I've changed my mind and like to use a WrapPanel..

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

then, I have to scroll down to the stackpanel closing tag and replace it ...

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Button />
</WrapPanel>
```

--> finished

Is it possible to do these last two steps in a single operation? Something like the rename refactoring in c# code would be useful...

Comment: I have never found a way within the native VS2010 to handle this need.  I finally settled on this technique:  collapse everything inside the container and delete the two tags.  Then highlight the collapsed line and invoke the 'Group into' function from Xaml Power Toys.

Comment: ok, that's another way, but imho not really easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you search on the [Visual Studio UserVoice forums](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio), you'll find a couple of refactoring requests. After a quick search I couldn't find one for your particular wish, so it might be a good idea to post a new feature request. You'd get my vote!

Otherwise, there's [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which is a Visual Studio plugin that does [what you're looking for](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/xaml_editor.html#XML_Editing_Helpers), unfortunately you have to pay for it, but there's a 30-day trial.

Answer (score 0):

Rename would certainly be nice.

Here's another option:

1. Go to the text of tag that you want to rename.
2. Bookmark the line (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+K).
3. Go to the matching tag (Ctrl+]).
4. Change the text of the tag.
5. Go to your bookmark (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+N).
6. Change the text of the tag.
7. Remove your bookmark (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+K).

Seems like a lot of steps, but it is much quicker done than read, especially if you're a keyboard whiz.

Good luck.